# How to install mono 4.0.5.1 (not latest) on Ubunty 16.04 LTS?

Tags: usb, system, mono

**BACKGROUND**

I recently upgraded from 15.10 to 16.04 and I have a problem with an application.  In fact it is quite possible that I have the same issue as [this guy](https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=38422#c0).

In my case here, I have the same CumulusMX problem:

```
Not working, 16.04: mono was Stable 4.4.2.11
Last working, 15.10: mono was Debian 3.2.8+dfsg-4ubuntu4
```

This seems to be in line with the following information I found [here](http://sandaysoft.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=27&t=12943#p101209):

> Mono 4.2 is known to not work with Cumulus MX with USB stations, for
>   reasons currently unknown

In a nutshell, I understand that the last `mono` version to support my weather station is 4.0.5.1 based on that other guy's problem.  This is what I would like installed.

**NEW 16.04 INSTALL**

I have re-installed Ubuntu and made the following changes:

```
$ sudo touch /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mono-xamarin.list
$ sudo vi /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mono-xamarin.list

# Type in:
# deb http://download.mono-project.com/repo/debian wheezy/snapshots/4.0.5.1 main
# and save.

$ sudo apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys A6A19B38D3D831EF
$ sudo apt update
```

I thought this would get me to be able to install the desired `mono` version as I get the following results:

```
$ apt-cache madison mono-devel
mono-devel | 4.2.1.102+dfsg2-7ubuntu4 | http://ca.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 Packages
mono-devel | 4.2.1.102+dfsg2-7ubuntu4 | http://ca.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/main i386 Packages
mono-devel | 4.0.5.1-0xamarin1 | http://download.mono-project.com/repo/debian wheezy/snapshots/4.0.5.1/main amd64 Packages
mono-devel | 4.0.5.1-0xamarin1 | http://download.mono-project.com/repo/debian wheezy/snapshots/4.0.5.1/main i386 Packages
```

However, the installation fails with the following:

```
$ sudo apt install mono-devel=4.0.5.1-0xamarin1
Lecture des listes de paquets... Fait
Construction de l'arbre des dépendances       
Lecture des informations d'état... Fait
Certains paquets ne peuvent être installés. Ceci peut signifier
que vous avez demandé l'impossible, ou bien, si vous utilisez
la distribution unstable, que certains paquets n'ont pas encore
été créés ou ne sont pas sortis d'Incoming.
L'information suivante devrait vous aider à résoudre la situation : 

Les paquets suivants contiennent des dépendances non satisfaites :
 mono-devel : Dépend: libmono-cecil-private-cil (< 4.0.5.2) mais 4.2.1.102+dfsg2-7ubuntu4 devra être installé
              Dépend: mono-mcs (= 4.0.5.1-0xamarin1) mais 4.2.1.102+dfsg2-7ubuntu4 devra être installé
              Dépend: mono-gac (= 4.0.5.1-0xamarin1) mais 4.2.1.102+dfsg2-7ubuntu4 devra être installé
              Dépend: mono-xbuild (= 4.0.5.1-0xamarin1) mais 4.2.1.102+dfsg2-7ubuntu4 devra être installé
              Dépend: libmono-cil-dev (= 4.0.5.1-0xamarin1) mais 4.2.1.102+dfsg2-7ubuntu4 devra être installé
              Dépend: libmono-2.0-dev (< 4.0.5.1-0xamarin1.1~) mais 4.2.1.102+dfsg2-7ubuntu4 devra être installé
              Recommande: mono-csharp-shell mais ne sera pas installé
E: Impossible de corriger les problèmes, des paquets défectueux sont en mode « garder en l'état ».
```

So from these results I understand I may be in dependancy horror land.  The results also literally say that I may be attempting the impossible.

**QUESTION**

What do i have to do to install `mono` 4.0.5.1?

Answer (score 0):

Had a similar problem recently. The issue here is that even if you specify a lower version of mono-devel, apt-get will still try and install the newest versions of its dependencies which, of course, will not work.

One can circumvent this by digging deeper into apt's internals and use the 'apt_preferences' mechanism.

For me, placing a file into /etc/apt/preferences.d with the following content solved the issue:

```
$ cat /etc/apt/preferences.d/mono
Package: /libmono.*/
Pin: release l=xamarin*
Pin-Priority: 990

Package: /^mono.*/
Pin: release l=xamarin*
Pin-Priority: 990
```

To explain the details briefly - for all packages that contain 'libmono' in their name or begin with 'mono', distributions with the label 'xamarin[1,2,...]' are preferred. 
This has the effect of ignoring ubuntu's newer (e.g. 4.2.1) packages for everything related to mono.

Comment: I created and filled the suggested file but I still cannot install with `sudo apt install mono-devel=4.0.5.1-0xamarin1`. I still get errors similar to the original post - what could I check?